# fix facebook like plugin error "Sorry, this feature isn't available right now"

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm trying to put several like buttons in my website using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/ .

When I press them in my website, the button's "like" caption turns to "error".
It WORKS okay in the preview on facebook developers.

When I click the error, a pop-up is opened and it's saying:
"Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: We're working on this issue and will have it fixed soon. Check the Known Issues on Facebook page for more information."
This has been appearing for hours!

What is this error about? Is my website blocked?

Answer (score -1):

I get the "Sorry this feature is not available right now".  I am beginning to believe that FB has locked me out.  They are not 'working' on anything.

When I first started playing in Facebook, I didn't know anyone personally, and I did not want to give out my personal information, so I never friend-ed anyone  unless there were a friend of someone I knew. I did not fill the info about myself entirely. Eventually this eased.

I must have used the same email address for both FB & Zynga.com, same address, same personal info for both but different  passwords.  How else can the same Farmville game be played on both.  I keep  forgetting passwords and have changed them so many times.  So now I am blocked out of Zynga too.  I was able to sign in with am e-mail that was used for Facebook so could play with those that liked playing.

Different address, but to the same account, farm, playing with the same friends.

Just so you know the phrase "not available...." means you are locked out permanently.